# Create view from json field in mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database

I have a field with json object with the  following structure:

```
{
"12edd9df-7aa3-5916-8e06-4f21dfcb5920": {"text": "value1", "deleted": true},
.... 
"23767bc4-2e30-5fca-8683-a04c06604e96": {"text": "value2", "deleted": true}
}
```

What is going to be sql for creation of view with the following structure:

```
uuid                                 | text    | deleted
12edd9df-7aa3-5916-8e06-4f21dfcb5920 | value1  | true
...
```

Constraints is that I'm using mysql 5.7, and can't create procedures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution. You will have to create a table of numbers for this to work.

```
CREATE TABLE n ( n INT PRIMARY KEY );
INSERT INTO n (n) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);

SELECT uuid, 
  JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$.', uuid, '.text')) AS text, 
  JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$.', uuid, '.deleted')) AS deleted
FROM (
  SELECT data, JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(data), CONCAT('$[', n, ']')) AS uuid
  FROM mytable CROSS JOIN n
) AS t 
WHERE t.uuid IS NOT NULL;
```

You should reconsider using JSON for this data. It would be much easier to write, debug, and maintain your code if you used normal columns.

You should be able to do this:

```
SELECT uuid, text, deleted FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, half of the project domain model depends on this kind of json fields, we will definitely refactor it in future, but for now just create a views for it. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Weeks of work refactoring can save you minutes of planning! :-) Seriously, that sounds like a terrible idea. Normalize the database first, then later refactor to _denormalize_ if necessary. You're doing it backwards!